# Error de SyntaxError: invalid syntax Python - Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hola saben que tengo un problema de sintaxis usando visual studio code con el lenguaje de programación Python, por favor ayudarme a como solucionar el error por favor!**

El programa trata de consultar datos consultando edad si es mayor o no, sistema de validación de usuario, solicitar ingresar notas por pantalla y calcular promedio, mostrar decimales y crear salida por pantalla con opciones múltiples.

```
line 19
    if ((usuario = {user1} and password = {pass1}) or (usuario = {user2} and password = {pass2})):
                  ▲
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Codigo completo:**

```
#1 consulta edad y si es mayor de edad o no.

edad = int(input("Ingrese la edad :"))
if (edad >=18):
    print("es mayor de edad ")
else:
    print("es menor de edad")

#2 sistema validacion de usuario

user1 = pedro
user2 = angel
pass1 = 1234
pass2 = a1s2

usuario = input("ingrese el usuario :")
password = input("ingrese contraseña :")

if ((usuario = user1 and password = pass1) or (usuario = user2 and password = pass2)):
    print(f"Bienvenido: {usuario}...")
else:
    print("Error, nombre o contraseña incorrecta")

#3 solicitar ingresar notas por pantalla y calcular promedio.
n1 = int(input("ingrese 1: "))
n2 = int(input("ingrese 2: "))
n3 = int(input("ingrese 3: "))

promedio = (n1+n2+n3) /3
if (promedio >39.5):
    print(f"Felicidades usted esta aprobado, su promedio fue : {promedio}")
else:
    print(f"Lamento informar que esta reprobado, su promedio fue :{promedio}")
#Para mostrar los decimales.
print("{0:.2f}".format(promedio))

#4 Crear salida por pantalla con opciones multiples.
print("¿Que animal vive en el agua?")
print ("a) Cocodrilo")
print ("b) Perro")
print ("c) Ballena")
print ("d) Condor")
puntaje = 0

opcion = input("...")
if (opcion == "a" or opcion == "A"):
    puntaje = 0.5
if (opcion == "c" or opcion == "C"):
    puntaje = 1
print(f"su puntaje fue {puntaje} puntos.")
```

Necesito conocer cual es la solución a este código para que no me cause tal error, es para una tarea de mis estudios, antemano gracias!

Comment: Error tipográfico, `=` es el operador de asignación, debes usar `==` operador de igualdad. Debe ser `if ((usuario == user1 and password == pass1) or (usuario == user2 and password == pass2)):` y no `if ((usuario = user1 and password = pass1) or (usuario = user2 and password = pass2)):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al solo colocar un = estas reasignando el valor

Tienes que manejar == para comprobación

El problema se encontraba de igual forma en tus variables ya que no le estabas indicando que fuera una cadena al tener solo digitos y digitos con letras mezclados te causaba un error se colocan dentro de las comillas y lo vuelves cadena STR

```
#2 sistema validacion de usuario

user1 = "pedro"
user2 = "angel"
pass1 = "1234"
pass2 = "a1s2"

usuario = input("ingrese el usuario :")
password = input("ingrese contraseña :")

if ((usuario == user1 and password == pass1) or (usuario == user2 and password == pass2)):
    print(f"Bienvenido: {usuario}...")
else:
    print("Error, nombre o contraseña incorrecta")
```

## Y queda de este modo

[image: Asi queda]

Comment: Me manda un error, dice que las variables user1 = pedro
user2 = angel no estan definidas

#2 sistema validacion de usuario

user1 = pedro
user2 = angel
pass1 = 1234
pass2 = a1s2

usuario = input("ingrese el usuario :")
password = input("ingrese contraseña :")

if ((usuario == user1 and password == pass1) or (usuario == user2 and password == pass2)):
    print(f"Bienvenido: {usuario}...")
else:
    print("Error, nombre o contraseña incorrecta")

Comment: Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'pedro' is not defined
  File "C:\Matias Seguro\Python Codes\ConsultaDeDatos.py", line 11, in <module>
    user1 = pedro

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo! fueron pequeños detalles pero muy importante al escribir código, que tengas una buena noche, abrazos.